# list with matrices times always the same vector

Tags: r, matrix, helper, mapply

i am working with consumer price index CPI and in order to calculate it i have to multiply the index matrix with the corresponding weights:

```
grossCPI77_10 <- grossIND1977 %*% weights1910/100 
grossCPI82_10 <- grossIND1982 %*% weights1910/100
```

of course i would rather like to have a code like the one beyond:

```
grossIND1982 <- replicate(20, cbind(1:61))
grossIND1993 <- replicate(20, cbind(1:61))
weights1910_sc <- c(1:20)
grossIND_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "grossIND...."))
totalCPI <- mapply("*", grossIND_list, weights1910_sc)
```

the problem is that it gives me a 1200x20 matrix. i expected a normal matrix (61x20) vector (20x1) multiplication which should result in a 20x1 vector? could you explain me what i am doing wrong? thanks

Comment: I did already.. just copy paste my code (the second block) above and it should give you a 1200x20 matrix

Comment: Is it desired in this question that `dim(replicate(20, cbind(1:61)))` is `[1] 61  1 20`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

part of your problem is that you don't have matrices but 3D arrays, with one singleton dimension. The other issue is that mapply likes to try and combine the results into a matrix, and also that constant arguments should be passed via MoreArgs. But actually, this is more a case for lapply.

```
grossIND1982 <- replicate(20, cbind(1:61))[,1,]
grossIND1993 <- replicate(20, cbind(1:61))[,1,]
weights1910_sc <- c(1:20)
grossIND_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "grossIND...."))
totalCPI <- mapply("*", grossIND_list, MoreArgs=list(e2 = weights1910_sc), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) 


totalCPI <- lapply(grossIND_list, "*",  e2 = weights1910_sc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood all aspects of your problem (especially concerning what should be colums, what should be rows, and in which order the crossproduct shall be applied), but I will try at least to cover some aspects. See comments in below code for clarifications of what you did and what you might want. I hope it helps, let me know if this is what you need.

```
#instead of using mget, I recommend to use a list structure
#otherwise you might capture other variables with similar names
#that you do not want
INDlist <- sapply(c("1990", "1991"), function(x) {

  #this is how to set up a matrix correctly, check `?matrix`
  #I think your combination of cbind and rep did not give you what you wanted
  matrix(rep(1:61, 20), nrow = 61)

}, USE.NAMES = TRUE, simplify = F)

weights <- list(c(1:20))

#the first argument of mapply needs to be a function, in this case of two variables
#the body of the function calculates the cross product
#you feed the arguments (both lists) in the following part of mapply
#I have repeated your weights, but you might assign different weights for each year
res <- mapply(function(x, y) {x %*% y}, INDlist, rep(weights, length(INDlist)))
dim(res)
#[1] 61  2
```